# Async google plus share function and get contents by not using meta content tags (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, facebook, angularjs, google-plus

I have here a Facebook implementation of `async` sharer.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'APP ID', status: true, cookie: true,
    xfbml: true});
};
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
    '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());

myApp.controller "socialShare", [
  "$scope"

  ($scope) ->
    $scope.share = (campaign) ->
      if campaign.description?
        description = campaign.description
        alert "test"
      else
        description= " "
      FB.ui
        method: "feed"
        name: campaign.name
        link: campaign.url
        picture: campaign.photo
        caption: campaign.description
        description: description
        message: ""

      return

    return
]
```

I can handle contents even w/o using meta tags (because content must be dynamic).

My question is that.. is it possible for Google plus to have the same idea? I'm having a hard time to fetch dynamic contents to OG tags. I would really like to implement what I did to FB.

Comment: FYI: The FB Feed dialog is deprecated, in the future you will only be able to use the Share dialog instead – and that does not accept those dynamic parameters any more either, but also fetches all the info from the OG meta info of the shared URL.

Comment: But feed is working as of now. thanks anyway for additional info.